# Retrieving `h1 id` in python using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Pretty simple really. For the following html code:

```
<h1 id="product-name" itemprop="name">Best product name !</h1>
```

I would like to retrieve ***Best product name !*** and to do so I am currently using:

```
prodname = soup.find(id="product-name")
prodname_clean = list(prodname.children)[0]
print(prodname_clean)
```

But on some occasions I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'
```

Why I get this error on some occasions and not others is a bit of a mystery but in any case my manner of retrieving *h1* is most probably not the best one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
>>> soup.find('h1').text
'Best product name !'
```

Or to be more precise,

```
>>> soup.find('h1', {'id': 'product-name'}).text
'Best product name !'
```

You can add more attributes in the dictionary, like

```
{'id': 'product-name', 'itemprop': 'name'}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the text in your h1 tag, you can just use `prodname.text`

---

Here's the code that I ran

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> a = BeautifulSoup('<h1 id="product-name" itemprop="name">Best product name !</h1>')
>>> a
<h1 id="product-name" itemprop="name">Best product name !</h1>
>>> a.find(id='product-name')
<h1 id="product-name" itemprop="name">Best product name !</h1>
>>> a.find(id='product-name').text
'Best product name !'
```

---

I could have used `a.text` as well